# ASPX - dynamic controls empty during Load but not ServerClick

Tags: c#, asp.net

We are creating controls dynamically which works fine on the front end and inside ServerClick handlers - we apply IDs so data is repopulated into the controls as expected.

However on one page, for simplicity we wanted to attach the dynamic controls during that page's Load event handler. We setup the grouping control's properties, then call DataBind() on it which uses LoadControl then PlaceHolder.Controls.Add to attach various controls dynamically based on rules.

As noted this all still works even at this later page life cycle stage. The problem is that for each dynamic control we add, when we go into its Load handler, the inputs are all still blank. So we cannot do any logic before ServerClick.

According to this diagram, ProcessPostData happens both before and after Load:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFBGj.jpg

I assume that's what is happening here. When we get to Load, the controls are blank. When we get to ServerClick, the controls are populated. Is there any way we can attach a handler in between these events? LoadComplete seems to be after ServerClick, so too late.

The MSDN documentation mentions 'catch-up', which might be happening here, but does not explain why the Load event happens before post data is loaded into the controls.

Our ServerClick handlers are at a different abstraction layer, and at multiple entry points, so should not be handling the logic we want to do, such as trimming and cleaning text inputs - this should be done by the control itself.

Moving the dynamic setup to Init instead of Load on the page fixes this issue - but is there a way to make it work if we set it up later?